# A sequence to continue, if you know how

Tags: number-sequence

What's the next number in this finite sequence?

> 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 3, 5, 4, 5, 2, 3, 5, 2, 3, 3, 1, 4, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3, ?

---

Hint added later:

> The sequence, though finite, does not terminate with the sought number.

Hint added even later:

> The "knowledge" tag is relevant here. (I'm not adding it so that people who don't want to peek at the hints don't see it.)

Hint added even later:

> Instead of "A sequence to continue, if you know how", I could've titled this "A sequence to continue, but you have to know how". (I'm not changing it so that people who don't want to peek at the hints don't see it.)

Comment: If that is a "finite sequence" is there just **one number** missing, which completes the sequence?

Comment: @WeatherVane, it doesn't imply that. Are you asking for an additional hint? I'll add one eventually if needed.

Comment: @msh210 puzzles like this are too broad

Comment: @Jan, you mean [tag:number-sequence] questions? If not, please clarify what it is about this one that makes it too broad where most such are not.

Comment: @msh210 so I can assume that when there is no "knowledge" tag, I can ignore real world. Also it is in Base10 and "finite sequence" means there are no numbers before or after what is here. But this way it is too general. It can be something like "lenght of words in Bible" or something like that.

Comment: @Jan, as I mentioned in an earlier comment, I'll gladly add hints as needed. I don't think that that time has come yet.

Comment: @JanIvan check the hints

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The next number is

> 9

The values represent

> The number of letters in each word of "The Cat in the Hat" by Dr. Seuss
>
> It starts with "The sun did not shine", which becomes 3, 3, 3, 3, 5 and the sequence runs up until "how I wish we had..." (3, 1, 4, 2, 3). The next word is "something" which is 9 letters long

Comment: Is the book well-known or has no revision? Means the sequence might could change also to the answer.

Comment: It's a fairly well-known children's book, I can't imagine they'd publish many/any revisions to the text

Comment: OK Roger that~~

Comment: Impressive. How did you find this? You must be a mind-reader! Anything from the hints that got you there?

Comment: How on earth does one puzzle this out?

Comment: rot13(Gur guveq pyhr jnf gur tvirnjnl, "ohg lbh unir gb xabj ubj" nccrnef va gur grkg juvpu vf jung tnir zr gur fbyhgvba)